# Pointer given as parameter to member function called in boost::thread_group is null

Tags: c++, boost, threadpool

I'm working with a threadpool with C++ and boost::thread_group but called method 'widgetProcessorJob' in thread get a null parameter (widget).
I tried to make it in different ways and I think that I'm using boost::asio badly...
I'm looking for someone who could tell me what I'm doing wrong and which way is the best way ?

```
void MarketingAutomation::processOnWidgets() {
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::thread_group threadpool;
    bool available = true; // need infinite loop in my program
    int offset = 0; // Only for batching

    boost::asio::io_service::work work(ioService);
    for (int i = 0; i < _poolSize; i++) {
        threadpool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
    }

    while (available) {
        std::shared_ptr<sql::ResultSet> widgets(MyDBConnector::getInstance().getWidgets(_batchSize, offset)); // just getting some data from sql base with mysqlcppconn

        if (!widgets->next()) {
            offset = 0;
            Logger::getInstance().logSTD("Restart widgets iteration !"); // this part is called when i did stuff on all batches
        } else {

            Logger::getInstance().logSTD("Proccess on " + std::to_string((offset / _batchSize) + 1) + " batch");

            // loop through the batch
            while (!widgets->isAfterLast()) {
                ioService.post(boost::bind(&MarketingAutomation::widgetProcessorJob, this, widgets));
                widgets->next();
            }

            threadpool.join_all();
            Logger::getInstance().logSTD("Finish on " + std::to_string((offset / _batchSize) + 1) + " batch");
            offset += _batchSize;

        }
    }
}

// Here is the function called in thread
void MarketingAutomation::widgetProcessorJob(std::shared_ptr<sql::ResultSet> widget) {
    WidgetProcessor widgetProcessor(widget, _kind); // Here widget is already null, but why ? :'(
    widgetProcessor.processOnWidget();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// loop through the batch
while (!widgets->isAfterLast()) {
    ioService.post(boost::bind(&MarketingAutomation::widgetProcessorJob, this, widgets));
    widgets->next();
}
```

You have only one `std::shared_ptr<sql::ResultSet> widgets`. By posting it multiple time you are making copies of the smart pointer, but all these smart pointers point to the same underlying `sql::ResultSet`.
This means that when you call `next()` you are "nexting" the same recordset you posted to all your handlers.

Now depending on the timing of execution of your threads and different race conditions, you might have gotten to the end of your recordset before any handler was even called and even if that's not the case, you are in a race condition that will get you, at best, only part of what you want.

Comment: Hi Drax thanks a lot for your replies, you point a mistake who could drive the program to a weird behavior but, luckily, I never wrote on this resultset ! However I finally found what's wrong and will post the correct answer in few hours or minutes.

Answer (score 1):

As I thought I used boost::asio badly ! After posting I tried  my program without infinite loop 'available' and jobs running with ioService made infinite loop because I never called stop method. To get the correct answer I moved thread_pool & io_service declaration/definition in the 'available' loop and call stop on each iteration ! Here is the correct answer including @Drax answer :

```
void MarketingAutomation::processOnWidgets() {
    bool available = true;
    int offset = 0;


    while (available) {
        std::shared_ptr<sql::ResultSet> widgets(SlaaskDBConnector::getInstance().getWidgets(_batchSize, offset));

        if (!widgets->next()) {
            offset = 0;
            Logger::getInstance().logSTD("Restart widgets iteration !");
        } else {

            boost::asio::io_service ioService;
            boost::thread_group threadpool;

            boost::asio::io_service::work work(ioService);
            for (int i = 0; i < _poolSize; i++) {
                threadpool.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));
        }

            Logger::getInstance().logSTD("Proccess on " + std::to_string((offset / _batchSize) + 1) + " batch");

            while (!widgets->isAfterLast()) {
                ioService.post(boost::bind(&MarketingAutomation::widgetProcessorJob, this, widgets->getInt("id")));
                widgets->next();
        }

            ioService.stop();
            threadpool.join_all();
            Logger::getInstance().logSTD("Finish on " + std::to_string((offset / _batchSize) + 1) + " batch");
            offset += _batchSize;

        }
    }
}

void MarketingAutomation::widgetProcessorJob(int widgetID) {
    WidgetProcessor widgetProcessor(widgetID, _kind); // Here widget is already null, but why ? :'(
    widgetProcessor.processOnWidget();
}
```